# Javascript DAT.Gui - is it a valid DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dat.gui

I would like to include into a `<td class="body_content">` a `DAT.Gui menu`. For this, I did :

```
// Create GUI
var gui = new dat.GUI({
 autoplace: false, 
    width: 350, 
    height: 15 * 32 - 1
});

var elementBodyContent = document.getElementsByClassName('body_content')[0];
elementBodyContent.appenChild(gui.domElement);
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error (on the last line above) :

```
TypeError: elementBodyContent.appenChild is not a function
```

I don't know how to circumvent this issue : is `gui` a valid DOM Element ?

Comment: Hint: if the error message says that `x` is not a function, then double-check what `x` is before you go looking for other issues... (The error you are getting has nothing to do with `gui.domElement`.)

Comment: I see you've edited the question, but you don't seem to have followed up on my hint. Do I have to *spell* it out?

Comment: like always, typo error with appendChild, sorry for all this stuff

Comment: This question can be closed as "Typo/Not Repro".